# Can use managed thread to call native function

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have native function takes 2 arguments , i want to create managed thread to call this function, supposing the function is `Func(arg1, arg2)` ... how can i call it via creating a new managed thread .. i mean using `System::Threading`.

Comment: There's no point in creating a thread just to call a native function.  Just call it directly.

Comment: how! can u write a sample code to do that

Comment: Func(1, 2);  You have to ask a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A managed (`System::Threading`) thread has to have a managed thread procedure.

That managed procedure can call native functions all it wants, of course, but when you pass a `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate, that has to be managed code.  Even if you manage to create a delegate pointing to native code, it's just because the compiler is creating a managed shim for you.